# Want to Use Gaussian kernel instead of Flat kernel in Sklearn mean shift clustering using python

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to do  mean shift clustering using [Sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.MeanShift.html) in python , they  use flat kernel in this clustering , but I want to use different kernel like Gaussian or Joint kernel . Can anyone help me to use Gaussian kernel/Joint kernel instead of Flat kernel ?

```
X = np.reshape(image, [-1, 3])
bandwidth = estimate_bandwidth(X, quantile=0.15, n_samples=500)
ms = MeanShift(bandwidth=bandwidth, bin_seeding=True ) 
# imported already Sklearn and required libraries  
ms.fit(X)
```

I'm new to python and also to Sklearn just for the records. They have [Gaussian kernel](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels.RBF.html) in Sklearn but I'm not understanding how can I use in above clustering.

Thank in advance!